# Flutter: How to execute an action only when we click on the notification using local_notification?

Tags: notifications, dart, flutter

I'm displaying notifications using [local_notification](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_notifications#-readme-tab-), and I would like to execute an action (for example, open the message of the new signal in a new window) when I click on the notification. I tried to use

```
onNotificationClick: new NotificationAction(actionText: "Open",
                callback: openSignal(signalEventFromCloud[i]),
                payload: "Open signal")
```

and the call back function is:

```
openSignal(Signal signal) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new DetailScreen(signal: signal),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This method call the callback function directly when the notification is displayed but I want to execute the callback function only if the user click on the notification.

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callback` needs to be a function, so change your code to read

```
onNotificationClick: new NotificationAction(actionText: "Open",
                callback: openSignal,
                payload: "Open signal")
```

otherwise openSignal gets called as the Widget is built, rather than as a result of the click.

However, you need to change openSignal to accept one String parameter

```
  openSignal(String signal) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new DetailScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

it's not clear what your parameter is for, but callback takes one String

Comment: I have this error: `[dart] The argument type '() → void' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(String) → dynamic'.`

Comment: I didn't realize that callback takes only String, thank you!